bitbucket, why would you ever want to use FF as it prevents being able to cherry pick PRs?
I have read a lot about commit methods, and seem many diagrams.  But I am still clueless about the underlying detail which is required to make sense of them. Ultimately, we need to pick one to always use all the time for all developers to make as a standard, to avoid developers choosing a random one.
bitbucket offers three merge methods:

merge commit
squash
fast forward.

In this blog: https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/pull-request-merge-strategies-the-great-debate/
It looks like merge commit (where you get a single commit (blob) from multiple PR commits, is the same as squash, in that both squash the commits of the PR and put it at the end of the master branch.  How are they actually different in practical terms?  Both end up with a single commit with all the changes of the PR in it.  In terms of history, if you dont delete the PR, you still have it.  If squash loses history of some sort, then presumably its bad, and one should always use "normal" Merge as a best practice?  We dont care about the individual commits within a PR.  Is this all that is "lost"?
Most diagrams of FF show your PR commits going at the end of the master branch.  In this case, I assume that cherry picking a PR (which has several commits) wont work, so I assume this should NEVER be used if you cherry pick (which we always do to create releases, and we cant see any other way to do it for a large project with many work streams)

Interesting. We actually change the behavior of merge once our software stabilizes and reaches maintenance. We Start of with a squash merge, as features and bug fixes get put together in a single commit. Making it easier to cherry pick for the release branches. But once it reaches to maintenance we move to merge commit allowing us to trace the parent from where it started of and why each step of change was done. The pain point in this is to cherry pick multiple commits for release. I have never seen FF work well with large team.
